# How to signal a ScheduledTask from a foreground app on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mutex

I'm creating an app that has a foreground app (of course) and both a PeriodicTask and a ResourceIntensiveTask.

I need a way to shutdown the scheduled tasks if the user launches the app itself while they are running.

I don't see any way of doing this with system-wide Mutexes.  Ideally when the background tasks started, a thread would be spun off that listens for a signal from the foreground app, and if it receives this signal it can shutdown the background task cleanly.

Other than polling (say a folder for a specific file), does anyone have a clean suggestion on how my foreground app can signal my background agents to close down if the foreground app is launched?

I'm heading towards sockets, but this seems like overkill.

**Background:**
I'm currently using IsolatedStorage to store my data (not a database) - eventually I'll move to using a database.

My foreground app synchronizes local data with a web service, and updates the UI when new items get added from the web service.  I use a file which I seek through to find data items, and which I append to as new items get synced.

I want background agents to run to perform this synchronization in the background, updating the files in isolated storage, including indexes, etc.  But as soon as I start up the foreground app, I need the background app to stop, so that the foreground and background don't both try to update the same files at the same time.

I need only one process to update the local data at a time, and I need the foreground process to preempt the background process.

Comment: I'd push for designing your agents to be able to run at the same time as the app. If you have a good example of something which means this couldn't be possible then I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: I've added some background info.  Essentially I can't have both processes modifying the same file at the same time, and I want the foreground process to preempt the background process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No concurrent update solution:**

*Application (`App()`)  :*

```
var m = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");
m.WaitOne(); //When PeriodicTask runs wait

if(lastSynchronization > 1.Minutes)
{  
  //Update only when your PeriodicTask not runs before 
}

//ApplicationExit      
m.ReleaseMutex();
```

*PeriodicTask (Main thread) :*

```
var m = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");
if(m.WaitOne(0)) // Dont wait for the handle
{
  // Synchronization

  m.ReleaseMutex(); 
}
else
{
  //Abort task (You dont want to wait for the main application)
}
```

**Stop PeriodicTask when Application starts solution:**

*Application (`App()`)  :*

```
var m = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");
m.WaitOne();

// Application    

m.ReleaseMutex();
```

*PeriodicTask (Separate thread) :*

```
var m = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");

while (m.WaitOne(0)) // Check for main application
{
   m.ReleaseMutex(); 
}

// Abort task
```

I think thats the best solution with the available members in WP7:

[`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=VS.96).aspx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)

Comment: I want my foreground app to signal my periodic task - the periodic task may already be running.  Achieving mutual exclusion is simple with mutexes, but signalling ... I'm not so sure.

Comment: When your Application starts it will acquire the handle and then your PeriodicTask cant acquire the handle anymore and will leave the while loop. Clear?

Comment: So you have a tight loop continually acquiring the lock and releasing it?  This will eat cpu, no?

Comment: :-)  I was hoping for a slightly more elegant interprocess signalling mechanism - I suspect it will be either this, or sockets.  I'd really like to avoid polling if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Interprocess communication via Named Events.

You can signal your background agent as soon as you open your foreground app.

http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents/

Comment: Thanks - AFAIK that wasn't available when I originally asked the question, but good to know for now.