# How to access main application data from ScheduledAgent?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to notify my main application (if it is still running) when the ScheduledAgent has finished its background task. 
Is it actually possible? I couldn't figure  out how I could reference my App or MainPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simply protecting shared data access between main app and background agent using `Mutex`es have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030715/how-to-signal-a-scheduledtask-from-a-foreground-app-on-windows-phone). Maybe this already gives you a hint in the right direction.

But if you want to react to events like "the background agent just finished" (in main app) or "the main app starts up" (in background agent) then you might be out of luck. There is no simple direct communication available, let alone direct data access. You could use [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) or Raw Notifications.

A method based on polling and `Mutex`es is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030715/how-to-signal-a-scheduledtask-from-a-foreground-app-on-windows-phone).