# How to use mutex for a database between background agent and foreground app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mutex, background-agents

How to use mutex for a database sync between background agent and foreground app? Can any one please help me to learn both of these for wp7(implementable code for wp7). Please try to add some code snippets that help me to understand the techniques in a simple way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want a mutex? if you are using SQL Ce, it supports multiple concurrent connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some articles that might be helpful for you:

[Implementing mutex and monitor in WP7 Mango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637183/implementing-mutex-and-monitor-in-wp7-mango)

[How to signal a ScheduledTask from a foreground app on Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030715/how-to-signal-a-scheduledtask-from-a-foreground-app-on-windows-phone)

http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Windows-Phone-Background-Agents-Pitfall-(3-of-n).aspx